# Keep synchronization when simplify features from different data source

Tags: simplify, openjump

We have two shapefile data sources:

1 `water-riverbank.shp`

With geometry type of `Polygon` which stands for the area of water

2`water-riverline.shp`.

With geometry type of `LineString` which stands for the direction of the water. We use these features to label the water.

[image]

Now we use mapshaper to simplify these data, however we may get this kind of result:

[image]

The simplified riverbank and riverline are not synchronized.

Any way to avoid this?

Comment: it's better to embed images rather than linking to them - it's easier for people to see them quickly, and you remove the chance that the links will become outdated

Comment: Probably not an extremely easy task. However, D-P simplificitation of lines does not remove start and end points. Perhaps the result would be fine if you could split your riverbank polygons into linestrings from the intersection points with rivers, simplify them and construct new polygons from the simplified linestrings.